# Cannot identify the issue with my a force modifier isn't apply to object. C# Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

Below is my code that I suspect could be the issue, but I'm unsure. Our PlayerController.cs is correctly applying force, but MoveStunKnock.cs is not showing that force is being applied to our Enemy object.

My debug logs show an odd behavior which I don't really understand. It shows the force being logged during the called stun state, instead of being called during the knock state. I came to this conclusion because the times the logs are displayed from stunned stay at 13:39:33, then the Knockback state happens at 13:39:35, then the force is applied after but at 13:39:33 which would technically be in our stunned state?

The enemy uses A* pathfinding by our EnemyController.cs, which happens during the move state, then when stunned by BatController.cs, the enemy object it will enter the stun state, then if the enemy object is attacked by the player while in its stun state, it should apply the force that is set in PlayerController.cs.

```
type using UnityEngine;
using Pathfinding;
using System.Collections;

public class MoveStunKnock : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum EnemyState { Move, Stunned, KnockedBack }
    public EnemyState CurrentState { get; private set; }

    private EnemyController enemyController;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private float stunEndTime;
    private IAstarAI astarAI;
    private BatController batController;
    private bool hasBeenHitByBat = false;
    private Vector2 pendingKnockbackForce;
    private Vector2 knockbackForce;
    private bool isKnockbackScheduled = false;

    void Start()
    {
        enemyController = GetComponent<EnemyController>();
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        CurrentState = EnemyState.Move;
        astarAI = GetComponent<IAstarAI>();
        batController = FindObjectOfType<BatController>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        switch (CurrentState)
        {
            case EnemyState.Move:
                if (IsPathfindingActive())
                {
                    HandleMovingState();
                }
                break;
            case EnemyState.Stunned:
                if (Time.time >= stunEndTime)
                {
                    TransitionToMove();
                }
                break;
            case EnemyState.KnockedBack:
                if (isKnockbackScheduled)
                {
                    Debug.Log($"{gameObject.name} knockback force applied: {knockbackForce}");
                    Debug.Log($"{gameObject.name} current velocity after knockback: {rb.velocity}");
                    isKnockbackScheduled = false;
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (CurrentState == EnemyState.KnockedBack && isKnockbackScheduled)
        {
            rb.AddForce(knockbackForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            Debug.Log($"{gameObject.name} knockback force applied: {knockbackForce}");
            isKnockbackScheduled = false;
        }
    }

    public void HandleBatCollision()
    {
        ApplyStunEffect();
    }

    private void HandleMovingState()
    {
        if (HasBeenHitByBat())
        {
            ApplyStunEffect();
        }
    }

    private void ApplyStunEffect()
    {
        float stunDuration = CalculateStunDurationBasedOnBat();
        GetStunned(stunDuration);
    }

    public void GetStunned(float duration)
    {
        CurrentState = EnemyState.Stunned;
        stunEndTime = Time.time + duration;
        enemyController.DisablePathfinding(); // Disable movement during stun
    }

    private float CalculateStunDurationBasedOnBat()
    {
        if (batController == null) return 0f;

        int rotations = batController.fullRotations; // Accessing the fullRotations directly

        if (rotations >= 3) return 2f;   // 3 or more rotations
        if (rotations == 2) return 1f;   // Exactly 2 rotations
        if (rotations == 1) return 0.5f; // Exactly 1 rotation

        return 0f; // No stun if less than 1 full rotation
    }

    public void PrepareForKnockback(Vector2 force)
    {
        if (CurrentState == EnemyState.Stunned)
        {
            knockbackForce = force;
            isKnockbackScheduled = true;
            Debug.Log($"{gameObject.name} knockback scheduled with force {force}");
            CurrentState = EnemyState.KnockedBack; // Transition to KnockedBack state
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator ApplyKnockbackForceCoroutine()
    {
        // Optionally, add a delay or other actions here

        if (pendingKnockbackForce != Vector2.zero)
        {
            rb.AddForce(pendingKnockbackForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            Debug.Log(gameObject.name + " is knocked back with force " + pendingKnockbackForce);
            pendingKnockbackForce = Vector2.zero; // Reset the pending force
        }

        yield return null; // Coroutine must yield something
    }


    public void MarkAsHitByBat()
    {
        hasBeenHitByBat = true;
    }

    private bool HasBeenHitByBat()
    {
        if (hasBeenHitByBat)
        {
            hasBeenHitByBat = false; // Reset the flag
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public bool IsPathfindingActive()
    {
        // Assuming 'astarAI' is the A* Pathfinding component
        return astarAI != null && astarAI.hasPath;
    }

    private void DisablePathfinding()
    {
        if (astarAI != null)
        {
            astarAI.isStopped = true;
        }
    }

    private void TransitionToMove()
    {
        CurrentState = EnemyState.Move;
        enemyController.EnablePathfinding(); // Re-enable movement
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Deathwall") && CurrentState == EnemyState.KnockedBack)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject); // Destroy or handle the enemy as needed
        }
    }
}here
```

I've tried a few things but really cannot pinpoint the issue being involved. I made the knockback schedule on a fixed update, hoping that could solve the physics issue. I've also tried in my Update.

Comment: as for your code, Im clearly not awake enough to untangle this.   It is not overly clear how you pick a lot of your options, and apparently only allows for 1 bat..   (the whole stun, hit by bat etc has no signs of how its called)  If things are happening out of order, you need to add a ton of debug messages, or even step through your code (but that always changes the outcome)